# JQuery Swiper manage different image size

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I use [JQuery swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WSlD_WiGMdU) to make a slideshow but if I have several image with different size `Jauery swiper` cant manage images properly.

Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
 Swiper('#swiper', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: 2000,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,

        nextButton: true,
        prevButton: true,

        zoom: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        calculateHeight: true,

        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 30,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the width on images to prevent overflow.

Something like `img { max-width: 100%; }`

Will need your HTML source to be able to diagnose any further.